# Angular material table - how to split all sub-elements into multiple rows

Tags: angular, typescript

I have data objects that I received from backend API that looks like this:

```
[{"testNumber":1,
   "students":[{"name":"Jane Doe","status":"PASSED"}, 
               {"name":"John Doe","status":"PASSED"}]},
 {"testNumber":2,
   "students":[{"name":"Jane Doe","status":"PASSED"}, 
               {"name":"John Doe","status":"FAILED"}]},
etc...
]
```

And this is my code to retrieve the names:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Student Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span *ngFor="let student of element.students"> {{student.name}} </span>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

However, with the above code all the names are combined into one cell like this: Jane DoeJohn Doe...

How do I split each name into one new row?
Essentially what I want to display is in this format:

```
| Student Name  | Test 1    | Test 2    | Test 3    | Test N    |
| Student 1     | Pass      | Fail      | Pass      | ...       |
| Student 2     | Pass      | Pass      | Pass      |           |
| Student 3     | Pass      | Pass      |           |           |
| Student 4     | Pass      |           |           |           |
```

Also what would be the best way to use ngFor and fill cell data for 'test 1', 'test 2', etc...?

This is my current data model in TypeScript (note that I control the backend services too so if data model change is required to make it easier on the front end, I could change it):

```
export class Test {
    testNumber: number;
    students: Student[];
}
export class Student {
    name: string;
    status: string;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It actually would simpler if you returned a collection of students instead of tests, where each student has a property `testResults: { testNumber: number, status: string}[]`. My answer is predicated on not changing the response payload from the API though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first want to set up your collection to more closely resemble the table you are displaying, which is a list of students with test statuses. Since your columns are dynamic, you will also want an array of tests as well that will represent the columns to show in the table.

```js
const getTests = of([
  {
    "testNumber":1,
    "students":[{"name":"Jane Doe","status":"PASSED"}, 
               {"name":"John Doe","status":"PASSED"}]},
  {
    "testNumber":2,
    "students":[{"name":"Jane Doe","status":"PASSED"}, 
               {"name":"John Doe","status":"FAILED"}]
  }
]);

getTests.subscribe(tests => {
  const studentMap = new Map<string, {}>();
  for(const test of tests) {
    for(const student of test.students) {
      const studentTests = {
        name: student.name,
        ...studentMap.get(student.name),
        [test.testNumber]: student.status
      };
      studentMap.set(student.name, studentTests)
    }
  }

  // columns
  this.testColumns = tests.map(t => t.testNumber);

  // table data: use this as the table data source
  this.students = Array.from(studentMap.values());
});
```

this will produce an array for students that looks like

```
[
  { "name": "Jane Doe", "1": "PASSED", "2": "PASSED" },
  { "name": "John Doe", "1": "PASSED", "2": "FAILED" }
]
```

So in your component, you can loop over each of the test numbers to make your columns:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Student Name</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let student">
    {{student.name}}
  </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container [matColumnDef]="testNumber" *ngFor="let testNumber of testColumns ">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Test {{testNumber}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[testNumber] }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris.
I do have further questions for you though if you don't mind as I just started learning Angular and TypeScript a few days ago.

1. Do you know why this code
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span *ngFor="let student of element.students"> {{student.name}} </span>
 </td>
would group all the student names into 1 single cell? How do I split it into multiple rows?

2. How do I grab the HttpClient observable response to an array and modify it (like the way you suggested) before passing it back to dataSource?

Comment: I figured it out for the 1st question. I needed to replace the span with a tr tag!

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can populate `students` and `testColumns` from an observable by subscribing in the component.